# Set the color of the line graph when past a guide line on amcharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I want to change the color of the line graph like they do with nagative values-> https://www.amcharts.com/demos/date-based-line-chart/.

The difference is that i need to change the color when its past an specific guide line, in my case i have four guide line and in the example i just can set one nagativebase and negativeLineColor.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you posted talks about [`negativeBase`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#negativeBase), which allows you to set a different baseline value in order to change the line color. You can set that equal to your guide value to achieve the effect you're looking for.

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  // ...
  "valueAxes": [ {
    // ...
     "guides": [{
       "value": 20,
       // ...
     }],
    // ...
  } ],
  "graphs": [ {
    // ...
    "negativeLineColor": "#67b7dc",
    "negativeBase": 20,
    // ...
  } ],
  // ...
});
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/43f2774431f476cc20145aa7fc9cf36d?editors=0010)

**Edit**

Multiple negative bases aren't supported out of the box, however you can overlay multiple graphs on top of each other with different negative base values while disabling their balloons and setting their base `lineColor` to `transparent`:

```
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "<div style='margin:5px; font-size:19px;'><span style='font-size:13px;'>[[category]]</span><br>[[value]]</div>",
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 0,
    "hideBulletsCount": 50,
    "lineThickness": 2,
    "negativeLineColor": "#ff0000",
    "negativeBase": 20,
    "valueField": "visits"
  },{
    "showBalloon": false,
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 0,
    "hideBulletsCount": 50,
    "lineColor": "transparent",
    "negativeLineColor": "#00ff00",
    "negativeBase": 10,
    "valueField": "visits"
  },{
    "showBalloon": false,
    "lineColor": "transparent",
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 0,
    "hideBulletsCount": 50,
    "negativeLineColor": "#0000ff",
    "negativeBase": -10,
    "valueField": "visits"
  },{
    "showBalloon": false,
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 0,
    "hideBulletsCount": 50,
    "lineColor": "transparent",
    "negativeLineColor": "#00ffff",
    "negativeBase": -20,
    "valueField": "visits"
  }],
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/718ac43d442dafde8e80957172286b9a?editors=0010)

Comment: Is my fault i didn`t mention that i have more that one guide line and i see that i just can set one negativeBase and one color. I need  four limits.

Comment: Got it. While it isn't possible out of the box, you can fake it by overlaying multiple graphs with the same `valueField` but different negative bases. I'll update my answer, but [here's a demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/718ac43d442dafde8e80957172286b9a?editors=0010) of this in action.

Comment: Thanks  it works. the main color get like a mix color but i will check. You really help me thanks to spend your time on my question.

Comment: You're welcome. I noticed the slight color mixing as well but there's no way around it with the current functionality.